# Python selenium How to click an element in iframe?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

My first test with selenium is to click a button on a website. The first button that I need to click is this "yes you can use cookies"-buttons in the popup of a website. But it seems that selenium doesn't find that button even though I added a wait line. I tried other buttons in the popup as well, but none of them can be found by my element_to_be_clickable. The element is in an iframe, so I guess I have to change to it, but it seems that I'm doing something wrong.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC  

driver_path = "D:/Python/learning_webclicker/firefox_driver/geckodriver.exe"
firefox_path = "C:/Program Files/Mozilla Firefox/firefox.exe"
option = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
option.binary_location = firefox_path
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=driver_path, options=option)

url = "https://web.de/"
driver.get(url)

WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it(driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/iframe")))
#I tried to find the "save-all-conditionally"-element with lots of different methods:
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "save-all-conditionally"))).click()
#WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, """//*[@id="save-all-conditionally"]"""))).click()
#WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "save-all-conditionally")))
# ...
```

This raises the error

```
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

And if I try to click the button directly after changing to iframe (or without checking for iframe), then I get

```
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
element=driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="save-all-conditionally"]""")
element.click()
>>> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: [id="save-all-conditionally"]
```

I guess, that I'm not really in the iframe (although frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it doesn't return an error), but I'm not sure how/what/why.

Comment: Too busy ATM, but try `WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[2]/iframe"))`. You may need an additional import, i.e., `from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By`.

Comment: Thank you, but I get the same result (I added a tuple around the (By.XPATH, "string") to avoid another error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The element you are looking after is inside `nested iframe`. You need to switch both the
iframes.

Use following css selector to identify the `iframe`.

```
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe[name='landingpage']"))) 
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe[src*='plus.web.de']")))
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "save-all-conditionally"))).click()
```

---

Or Use below `xpath` to identify the iframe.

```
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@name='landingpage']"))) 
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[contains(@src,'plus.web.de')]")))
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "save-all-conditionally"))).click()
```